# Chrome extension - button listener on notification executes multiple times

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a chrome extension that makes requests to an API and I have noticed that after I create a notification from background script using chrome's notification API, the listeners on the buttons from the notification are executed multiple times. on the first run only once and then increasing. I figured that the listeners just add up on the page but I couldn't find a way to sort of refresh the background page.

This is the function that creates the notification and it's listeners.

```
var myNotificationID
const displayNotification=(userEmail, password, website,username) =>{
    chrome.notifications.create("", {
        type:    "basic",
        iconUrl: "./icon128.png",
        title:   "PERMISSION",
        requireInteraction: true,
        message: "question",
        buttons: [{
            title: "YES",
        }, {
            title: "NO",
        }]
    }, function(id) {
        myNotificationID = id;
    })

    chrome.notifications.onButtonClicked.addListener(function(notifId, btnIdx) {
        if (notifId === myNotificationID) {
            if (btnIdx === 0) {
                console.log('inserting')
                try{
                    fetch (`http://localhost:8080/users/${userEmail}/accounts`,{      
                    })
                }catch(err){ 
                }
            } else if (btnIdx === 1) {
                console.log('clearing')
                chrome.notifications.clear(myNotificationID)
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And this is where the function is called

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, response)=>{
    if(message.message === 'showNotification'){
        console.log('received insert')
        displayNotification(message.userEmail,message.password, message.currentSite,message.username)
        response({status:"received"})
    }
})
```

the fetch within the listener is executed multiple times but the log from the onMessage listener is only displayed once, so the listener is the problem here.
I tried chrome.notifications.onButtonClicked.removeListener(), but as i mentioned there was no success.
Are there any other ways in which i could clean the listeners from the background script once they are used?

Comment: You are nesting the chrome.notifications.onButtonClicked.addListener on your display function, wich fires everytime you display a notification, have you tried moving the listener to the upper scope of displayNotification?

Comment: @savageGoat it looks like it could solve my problem, but then i wouldn't have access to the parameters from that function. are there any workarounds for that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question... the onButtonClicked listener provides the notificationID and the button index, that verification is done by checking myNotificationID, wich is already in the upper scope set here `myNotificationID = id;`

Comment: if i understand this question in another way, I'd say that you could set a notification store that handles all the values in an object with notifications IDs as keys

Comment: @savageGoat I am referring to the parameters from displayNotification that i get from the message listener. I made use of those also in the listener when i performed the fetch. i am trying to set those values to a global object but i can't access it apparently

Comment: I think you have what you are looking for in the answer I posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a notification store:

```
const notificationsByID = {};

chrome.notifications.onButtonClicked.addListener((notifId, btnIdx) => {
    // Avoid access to the notification if not registered by displayNotification
    if (!notificationsByID[ notifId ]) { return null; }
    if (btnIdx === 0) {
        console.log('inserting')
        try{
            fetch (`http://localhost:8080/users/${ notificationsByID[ notifId ].userEmail }/accounts`,{ /**/ });
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        delete notificationsByID[ notifId ]; // Cleanup
    } else if (btnIdx === 1) {
        console.log('clearing')
        chrome.notifications.clear(myNotificationID);
        delete notificationsByID[ notifId ]; // Cleanup
    }
});

chrome.notifications.onClosed.addListener((notifId) => {
    if (notificationsByID[ notifId ]) { delete notificationsByID[ notifId ]; }
});

const displayNotification=(userEmail, password, website,username) =>{
    chrome.notifications.create("", {
        type:    "basic",
        iconUrl: "./icon128.png",
        title:   "PERMISSION",
        requireInteraction: true,
        message: "question",
        buttons: [{ title: "YES", }, { title: "NO", }]
    }, function(id) {
        // Insertion
        notificationsByID[ id ] = { userEmail, password, website,username };
    })
}
```